# TypeError: (0 , _codeSigningCertificates).signBufferRSASHA256AndVerify is not a function (Expo Go)

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

Can't launch my app after a few switches between commits. Expo go shows the error in console

`TypeError: (0 , _codeSigningCertificates).signBufferRSASHA256AndVerify is not a function (Expo Go)`

and on device [image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF7E4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF7E4.png)]

I tried to reinstall dependencies and I reloaded app few times, but this didn't help. After a few time I finally launched my app, but I didn't change anything. And then I switched on another branch and caught this error again.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure its connected with Sentry. I am not using it and the problem occurred in my app.
It happened when I upgraded Expo SDK from 46 to 48 on one branch and later switched to another that still uses SDK 46.

I think there is some problem with packages, because in my case removing `node_modules` and running `yarn` again solved this problem.

Comment: I can confirm this. Happend to me after upgrade. Runing `rm -rf node_modules` and then `yarn install` fixed the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks like during the upgrade 2 different versions of @sentry/react-native get installed (one as a strict dependency of sentry-expo and another one is automatically upgraded by expo-cli), and metro gets confused.

> As a temporary solution, forcing a single version of @sentry/react-native via resolutions did the trick for me (according to sentry-expo peerDependencies 4.2.2 is a correct version):

```
"resolutions": {
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.2.2"
},
```

this solution is from [github](https://github.com/expo/sentry-expo/issues/281)